# Is there any way to invert the flight controls?

Tags: diddy-kong-racing-ds

I really hate flying the plane. I am not very good at it, especially when I have to remember that pressing up makes my plane go down and down makes my plane go up.

Is there any way to invert this on the DS version? It would probably make the flying races a lot easier for me.

Comment: I almost understand people who don't invert the Y for non-mouse FPS use, but flying?  GET OFF MY LAWN.  :P

Comment: The controls you describe are already inverted. Perhaps you're looking for a way to vert the flight controls instead?

Comment: This is something that you might want to get used to. Most games that have a flying aspect emulate a real plane, in which you control the direction of the tail of the plane and not the nose.

Comment: Really? Those are the controls I PREFER when flying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start the game and choose your save file, choose the right hand option (options) then choose the top option (game settings).

The option to invert the Y axis in in there.